# app crash with android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-context

i need help. 
I'm in the finish phase of development of my android application and now after a few month of develop the app magically crash with this error :

```
java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

I don't know what is the problem but i will post the code that cause the crash :

```
   public static void start(Context context) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ConversationsActivity.class));
    }
```

called with this piece of code (inside a fragment):

```
ConversationsActivity.start(getActivity());
```

The last change that i've make was to add Fabric.io ( in particular Branch ) and from the history in the last commit on git i don't show nothing that can produce this error

**EDIT :**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128) 
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4900)
at com.exampleapp.views.messages.ConversationsActivity.start(ConversationsActivity.java:31)
at com.exampleapp.views.menu.MenuFragment.onMenuMessagesClicked(MenuFragment.java:116)
at com.exampleapp.views.menu.MenuFragment_ViewBinding$5.doClick(MenuFragment_ViewBinding.java:82)
at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace.

Comment: i've update the question

Comment: `getActivity()` appears to be returning `null`. I am not completely certain why.

Comment: yes , now i show that also in other parts of code the context/activity retrieved with getContext() or getActivity() result null.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could do this:

```
public static void start(Activity activity) {
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, ConversationsActivity.class));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `getActivity()` to launch an `Activity` from `Fragment`.

**From a Fragment:** `Context` is parent activity `(getActivity())`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ConversationsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**From an Activity:** `Context` is current activity `(this)`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConversationsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using the intent wrong. Replace your start() code with this:

```
public static void start() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConversationsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then instead of using `ConversationsActivity.start(getActivity());` to call it, just use `start();` when you want to call the method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer but i don't think this is the solution , also because it has always worked. Why ApplicationContext?

Comment: Just try this, it always works for me. Application Context is always a safe choice

Comment: nothing to do man :( but now i realised that the same code work with different activity called from other fragment O.o i have no idea about what happened